# Performance Cost of Using @FetchRequests in SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui

So my question is sort of two fold as I am fairly new to SwiftUI and working with CoreData.

My first question, and maybe I'm not doing this the right way but, if all of my views need access to the results from a FetchRequest that has my CoreData stack, will it be costly to call that FetchRequest in every view? I've seen some post discuss that especially when dealing with lists this can cause the UI to stutter a lot and am not sure if this is still an issue and with how much data is needed to experience this. For context I'm working on a budget app so I would have ~26 Objects per year which isn't a lot at first but over time say roughly 4 years would 100 object be enough to hinder performance?

Following this up, from my experience, CoreData objects are a huge pain to pass around (and maybe its because I'm doing it though a fetch request). Is it common practice to load the CoreData stack into your own data structure and pass that around your app for displaying and editing info and obviously still perform saves and deletes on the core data object when necessary. It seems like this would be a lot easier at least for displaying my objects.

Also, I have a decent understanding of CoreData, but I feel like there's a lot of stuff I am not doing the best way and everything I see online is just like getting core data set up, not much on best ways to go about doing certain things so any links to good practices would be appreciated.

Comment: Regarding your first question ("would 100 be enough to hinder performance"), I'm going to generally say "no", but one could easily make a coding mistake (like making a query that loads all 100 for *each* cell in a `List` but only displaying one) that could bog down performance. Without actual code to look at, it's speculation.

Comment: [The Laws of Core Data](https://davedelong.com/blog/2018/05/09/the-laws-of-core-data/) is a good read and Donny Wals has a lot of good articles in [his blog](https://www.donnywals.com/the-blog/) and you could of course also by his Core Data book